Choose Transistor and Op-Amp for Constant Current Source Driven by Microcontroller
for my project I am trying to provide a current source to a heater (load in the diagram) on a PID loop to keep an object at constant temperature.
A thermocouple is attached that reads the temperature. The thermocouple output goes to a Beaglebone Black which can has an variable output of up to 3.3 V and 250 mA. I need around 1.5 A to power the heater so I found the diagram for a constant current source.

My issue is I have only a basic understanding of these circuits so I do not know how to find the op-amp and MOSFET required for this circuit. I know that I need an n-type MOSFET that can allow up to 1.5 A of current and has a variable control from 0-3.3 V, and an op-amp with slow timescale and high input impedance. Sources that I have found claims the MOSFET works as a variable resistor but I am unsure how to choose one which will work the way I need it to.
Information on circuits beyond basic level stuff is hard to find and difficult to fully understand. How would I begin selecting these parts? I was hoping this circuit would be an efficient and cheap way to drive a constant variable current but if it is not then I will have to buy a voltage controlled power supply which is very simple but a bit more expensive.

Do you absolutely need constant current control?  The thermal time constant of even a small heater is orders of magnitude longer than a slow (few dozen Hz) PWM scheme. It would simplify your control loop and remove the need to heatsink your pass element.

You can run the control loop in analog/linear mode (as you've suggested).  However, you will find that just turning the heater full-on/off will usually be easier and effective (less circuitry too).  This is how most common temperature controllers work.

Will, how much power will be dissipated in your 2Ω regulation resistor, compared to the load (hint: exactly the same amount!). And even if you didn't have that  resistor,  the difference between the voltage over the load and the supply voltage must always be dissipated in your transistor. So, this is a non-starter, unless you can cool the transistor better than the heater can heat whatever it is that you're heating.

Thank you for all of the excellent suggestions! Based on the full on-off scheme it will be easier to control using a solid-state relay so I don't have to mess with transistors.

As far as I can tell, the Beaglebone Black doesn't have an analogue output, so this design is a bit of a non-starter. You would need to use PWM in some way as others have said. But a MOSFET would work fine as as an on/off switch without the expense of an SSR.

You might find this question and its answer helpful

@WillBrunner you must not have read my comment very closely: the transistor isn't the problem! The problem is the idea that you would turn on something "halfway" to drop the voltage that you don't want to drop in the load is the problem. You don't need an solid-state relay for an ohmic load! An n-channel MOSFET as switching element is just fine. You just need make sure that for any instant in time, you switch it either on and off, and not "somewhat on".
